# Computer Crash Question

Tags: 12.04, unity, kernel

I was running Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba laptop last night. I installed it about 6 days ago.

Yesterday I made some changes to get rid of Unity and use Gnome Classic. Everything was fine all day and night until I rebooted then I got the following error:

> could not write bytes: Broken pipe:
>
> - No suitable module for running kernel found
> - Starting the Winbind daemon winbind
>
> amed disabled: edit /etc/default/sancd

I had to do a complete re-install this morning.

Can anyone explain this error to me and why it might have happened so I can avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weeeell, I have spent allot of time researching this problem today to no avail...

Until I tried to re-install Virtual Box again. Everything went fine, it installed ok no problems...

Then I read somewhere that I needed to update the dkms, so I did but through the terminal this time... Well I checked to see how it was progressing and what did I find `"* No suitable module for running kernel found"`. The same error I got after my computer crashed, no less...

Do not know exactly how they did it but the dkm update, up"rooted" my laptop and killed it...

So I uninstalled virtual box along with the dastardly dkms today, and now all is well...